# MAX function returning multiple values for each group

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, max

I'm trying to create a query to show the current account from each branch
that is also a joint account, that has the highest free overdraft limit.

I've almost got it working, but it is seems to be returning all joint current accounts for branches (branches 1 and 3 only have one current account that is a joint account so that is why they are only ones returning one value)

I believe it may have something to do with the GROUP BY function but if I remove any of the attributes from the GROUP BY clause it says it is not a valid GROUP BY.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
    SELECT MAX(a.freeOverdraftLimit), b.branchAddress.streetAddress, b.branchAddress.city, b.branchAddress.postcode, b.branchID, c.pname.forename, c.pname.surname
    FROM kt_accountTable a
    JOIN kt_branchTable b ON a.branchID = b.branchID
    JOIN kt_customerAccount c ON a.accountNum = c.accountNum
    WHERE jointAccount = 'Y' AND accountType = 'Current'
    GROUP BY b.branchID, b.branchAddress.streetAddress, b.branchAddress.city, b.branchAddress.postcode, c.pname.forename, c.pname.surname
    ORDER BY COUNT(a.freeOverdraftLimit);
```

[Account Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/780DR.png)

[Branch Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6pL2.png)

[Customer Account Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrQly.png)

[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcoR1.png)

Comment: paste your query as text instead of screenshot

Comment: Not only is it very difficult to read screenshots, it is also very difficult to analyze a query without know the table structures.   Please read, and heed, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Apologies, I've now pasted the query as text and included links to images of the relevant tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

There is nothing in your query that specifies the condition to limiting to the account with the *highest* free overdraft limit.

Since you tagged your question "Oracle", I'll assume you are using a relatively recent version and walk through how to do this using the `CROSS APPLY` join feature.

Since you want your result set to show one row per branch, start with just that table...

```
SELECT b.branchAddress.streetAddress, 
       b.branchAddress.city, 
       b.branchAddress.postcode, 
       b.branchID
FROM   kt_branchTable b
```

Next, use `CROSS APPLY` to find the ONE account having the highest overdraft limit, using the accountNumber to break ties.
(NOTE: Assumes every branch has at least one account.  If not a good assumption, use `OUTER APPLY/`)

```
SELECT a.freeOverdraftLimit, 
       b.branchAddress.streetAddress, 
       b.branchAddress.city, 
       b.branchAddress.postcode, 
       b.branchID
FROM   kt_branchTable b
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT a.freeOverdraftLimit, a.accountNum
              FROM   kt_accountTable a
              WHERE  a.branchId = b.branchID
              ORDER BY a.freeOverdraftLimit DESC, a.accountNumber ASC
              FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY ) a
```

From here, it's easy to add in the customer info for that account, giving you your final answer as follows:

```
SELECT a.freeOverdraftLimit, 
       b.branchAddress.streetAddress, 
       b.branchAddress.city, 
       b.branchAddress.postcode, 
       b.branchID, 
       c.pname.forename, 
       c.pname.surname
FROM   kt_branchTable b
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT a.freeOverdraftLimit, a.accountNum
              FROM   kt_accountTable a
              WHERE  a.branchId = b.branchID
              ORDER BY a.freeOverdraftLimit DESC
              FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY ) a
INNER JOIN kt_customerAccount c ON c.accountNum = a.accountNum
```

NOTE: it's not clear from your data model whether multiple customers can own the same account (i.e., two rows in `kt_customerAccount` having the same `accountNumber`.  If so, this solution will give duplicates.  But you did not specify the requirements for handling that situation (show all, show first, etc.), so I'm not handling it as part of my answer here.